# SQL запрос со сложным условием

Tags: mysql, sql, mysqli, запрос

Помогите составить sql запрос. Есть таблица:

```
tb_users(user_id, name)
```

И таблица связи (друзей):

```
tb_friends(from_id, to_id)
```

Нужно выбрать пользователя с `name` похожий на `$user` и чтобы его `user_id` был не раен `to_id` из таблицы `tb_friends` где `from_id` равен 1 (`from_id=1`)

Мой неправильный вариант запроса:

```
mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM tb_users
WHERE name LIKE '%$user%'
AND user_id != (SELECT to_id FROM tb_friends WHERE from_id =1));
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SELECT name
FROM tb_users u
LEFT JOIN tb_friends f
       ON  u.user_id = f.to_id 
       AND f.from_id = 1
WHERE u.name LIKE '%$user%'
  AND f.to_id IS NULL
```